# Using python pex as interpreter doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pex

I have a python pex file that I want to use as a python interpreter. I set the .pex in vscode as python interpreter and vscode recognized it correctly as python interpreter, but when I click on run, it doesn't do anything. There is no debug or output print anywhere that I can see. The same pex file works fine from command line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vscode python interpreter only supports the recognition of `python.exe`. The content you mentioned is provided by the **pex** package which is not a VsCode built-in package, and VsCode itself does not support it at present.

Currently, vscode supports the recognition of **conda** and **venv** in virtual environment.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details.